# Append and remove part of an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code appends `someText` to an input value on submit of a form.

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
var someText = 'Some text';
var newText = 'New text';
$('#someid').val($('#someid').val() + someText);
});
```

Now, on re-submit of form, the `someText`appends twice, as it was appended on the first submit.

I need on **re-submit** of the form, to append `newText` to the input value and remove `someText` that was appended in the first submission.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace()` method before appending:

```
$('#someid').val($('#someid').val().replace(someText, "") + someText);
```

or a better way:

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    var someText = 'Some text';
    var newText = 'New text';
    var newValue = $('#someid').val().indexOf(someText) != -1 ? $('#someid').val().replace(someText, "") + someText : someText;
    $('#someid').val(newValue);
});
```